# Как убрать только боковые отступы у col-4 в Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как убрать эти крайние отступы у bootstrap col-4?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если убираю у них padding, то они вовсе сплющиваются:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Примерный код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выше на страничке, что на скриншотах, реализация была по другому сделана, там не использовались col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -1) !important;
}

.col-4 div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```